# How to use a variable with a Property After

Tags: excel, vba

This should be simple. I am working with userforms. I want to save a number that is stored in a cell and concatenate it with "lbl" and store it in a variable called Label. This works. I Then need to use the property .Caption but get a 424 error. Replacing the variable with what is stored in it ("lbl1"), the code runs.

Not sure why this is not working. Any help appreciated.

```vb
Sub ErrorExample()

    Dim Label As String
    
    'Clear previous click
    If Worksheets("BackEnd").Range("D2").Value = "" Then
        'No previous click
    Else
        
        'This does not work
        Label = "lbl" & Worksheets("BackEnd").Range("D2").Value
        With Label
            'Clear previous click
            .Caption = ""
        End With
        
        
        'This works
        With lbl2
            'Clear previous click
            .Caption = ""
        End With
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Label is a string variable.  It does not have a caption property.  You don't show the definition of lbl2.

Answer (score 1):

### Userform: Reference a Control By Its Name

- Copy the code into the user form's module.

```vb
Private Sub ToClearOrNotToClear()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BackEnd")
    
    Dim Label As String: Label = CStr(ws.Range("D2").Value)
    
    Dim lbl As Control
    
    If Len(Label) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Set lbl = Controls("lbl" & Label)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If lbl Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Label not found!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Len(CStr(lbl.Caption)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Label is clear!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        lbl.Caption = ""
        MsgBox "Label cleared.", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```